# Nunit Extent Report for Multiple Classes not reporting correctly

Tags: c#, nunit, extentreports

I have a Nuit Test with Extent Report 4 configured for multiple classes. I am getting the extent report result correctly for the first class but its not reporting the 2nd class status (Only one class is reporting at a time)

Here is the class created for ExtentReprot

```
namespace ReportTestProject
    {
    [TestFixture]
    public class SetupFixture1
    {
        public static ExtentReports _extent;
        public static ExtentTest _test;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void StartReport()
    {
        _extent = new ExtentReports();
        var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports");
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports" + "\\Automation_Report" + ".html");
        _extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "DEV");
        _extent.AddSystemInfo("User Name", "RAKESH");
        _extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

        _test = _extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void aftertest()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stacktrace = "" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + "";
        var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
        Status logstatus;

        switch (status)
        {
            case TestStatus.Failed:
                logstatus = Status.Fail;
                _test.Log(logstatus, "Test " + logstatus + " – " + errorMessage + stacktrace);
                break;
            default:
                logstatus = Status.Pass;
                _test.Log(logstatus, "Test " + logstatus);
                break;
        }
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void AfterClass()
    {
        _extent.Flush();
    }
    }
}
```

here is my first class

```
namespace ReportTestProject
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass1 : SetupFixture1
    {
        [Test]
        public void PassTest1()
        {
            _test = _extent.CreateTest("PassTest1");
            var answer = 42;
            Assert.That(answer, Is.EqualTo(42), "Some useful error message");
        }

        [Test]
        public void FailTest1()
        {
            _test = _extent.CreateTest("FailTest1");
            var answer = 43;
            Assert.That(answer, Is.EqualTo(42), "answer is not 42 so test failed");
        }
    }
}
```

And the second class

```
namespace ReportTestProject
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass : SetupFixture1
    {
        [Test]
        public void PassTest2()
        {
            _test = _extent.CreateTest("PassTest2");
            var answer = 42;
            Assert.That(answer, Is.EqualTo(42), "Some useful error message");
        }

        [Test]
        public void FailTest2()
        {
            _test = _extent.CreateTest("FailTest2");
            var answer = 43;
            Assert.That(answer, Is.EqualTo(42), "answer is not 42 so test failed");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is, Extent report only showing the result from Test Class 1. Please see screenshot below

[image]

What I am doing wrong here. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your OneTimeTearDown method in AssemblySetup class.

```
[SetUpFixture]
    public class AssemblySetup
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void Setup()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-AT");

        }


        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void EndReport()
        {
              _extent.Flush();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in NUnit and Extent Report for multiple classes. I was able to resolve it after I created the _extent instance outside the [OneTimeSetUp] hook.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SetupFixture1
{
    public static ExtentReports _extent = new ExtentReports();
    public static ExtentTest _test;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void StartReport()
    {
        var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports");
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports" + "\\Automation_Report" + ".html");
        _extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "DEV");
        _extent.AddSystemInfo("User Name", "RAKESH");
        _extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

        _test = _extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
    }
}
```